# Importing models to forms in Django

Tags: django

I am making a quiz web application and I want to create answers to questions from admin panel, not writing a code for each set of answers. How can I do that?

forms:

```
from django import forms

ANSWER_CHOICES = [
    ('1', 'First'),
    ('2', 'Second'),
    ('3', 'Third'),
]
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = '',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=ANSWER_CHOICES,
    )
```

models:

```
from django.db import models

class Questions(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Question', max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your models.py:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    
    OPTION_CHOICES = [
        ('option1', 'option1'),
        ('option2', 'option2'),
        ('option3', 'option3'),
        ('option4', 'option4'),
    ]
    
    question = models.TextField(unique=True)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text='Required')
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=201,help_text='Required')
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=202,null=True,blank=True,help_text='(Optional)')
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=204,null=True,blank=True,help_text='(Optional)')
    answer = models.CharField(choices=OPTION_CHOICES,max_length=205,help_text='This answer must be match for given above option..')
    answer_hidden = models.CharField(max_length=206,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='True Answer',help_text="Your selected option's answer",default='No select any ans. yet!!')
    point = models.IntegerField(default = 1,help_text='Student How many points will get for this given question?')
    solution = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,help_text='(Optional) If possible! give the specific solution for this question..')
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name='Created Date')
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Questions"
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.answer == 'option1':
            self.answer_hidden = self.option1
            super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        elif self.answer == 'option2':
            self.answer_hidden = self.option2
            super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        elif self.answer == 'option3':
            self.answer_hidden = self.option3
            super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        elif self.ans2wer == 'option4':
            self.answer_hidden = self.option4
            super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question)
```

> select option from the admin panel -> this selected option's ans.
> automatic save in hidden_answer field -> show this ans. in front-end

I already made this app [Quiz_app](https://github.com/Pradip369/Quiz-App/blob/main/quizeapp_zip.zip)

Comment: oh man thanks, but I have few questions. First of all what is "super" you are using in if conditions and what are they for? And  secondly what is a "verbose name" (I am a beginner)

Comment: Welcome Myrodis. Ans. 1) super(Question, self).save(...) call save method of  "parent class" or "superclass" of Question class.[More detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20170820065901/http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#using-super-example) Ans. 2) verbose_name is a human-readable name for the field. If the verbose name isn't given, Django will automatically create it using the field's attribute name, converting underscores to spaces.

Comment: and do I need to do anything in the forms? or is it all I need

Comment: No, Now fetch all the questions and show in frontend by using `views `and `urls`...May be need to create `login` or `register` form it's depend on your requirement.